# magento: bulk delete products via import/export facility?

Tags: magento

I'm using import/export advanced profile to import products CSV file. The question is, how do I bulk delete certain products using the same facility? I can target SKU's of products to be deleted and modify CSV file as I see fit.

Marking "status" as "disabled" in import file won't work, because I also have some disabled products on magento that will be enalbed at some point.

My version of Magento is 1.4.2.0

Comment: What happens if some of the items you want to delete are bundle items and have associated photos?

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question but maybe this answer also helps somebody googling.

Bulk delete of selected products is really easy with [MAGMI](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=What_is_magmi) I use it in the magento project I work on (I'm not affiliated with MAGMI creator.) The docs describe a [bulk delete via csv](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Product_Deleter) but if you use the sqldatasource plugin you can do the same by adding the magmi:delete column in your table.

Comment: I would also prefer MAGMI for this task; can you confirm it works down to 1.4.2.0? Anyway, +1 in case someone get's here from Google!

Answer (score 1):

It's Magento default provide functionality using csv import.
**Go to Admin >> System >> Data Trasfer >> Import.
https://prnt.sc/26ct8w6**

CSV file should contain one column with "sku". Upload CSV file and choose the delete option from Import Behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one time data load, you may better off exporting your products and then [deleting your entire products](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-knowledge-base/mass-delete-products-in-magento/), remove the product entries in the export and re-import.  You could also customize the import to remove products if it is not for a one time load, you can also look into using [uRapidFlow](http://www.unirgy.com/products/urapidflow/) as well.

Comment: It is a one time data load, however there are plenty of manually created products that would get deleted, so that's not an option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating  a php script in base directory of your magento,using the script read the sku from the csv file.Then after loading the product collection based on sku. You can delete the products.

OR

you need to create as adapter by extending the existing adapter for deleting the products specified by sku. Then you need to specify that adapter in profile action xml in Advanced import/export profile.
example:

```
  <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_productimportcustomoptiondelete</var>
```